# Issue while executing a template haskell splice to generate a new class instance

Tags: haskell

Well the point is that I have defined a function that given a list of Strings it returns a list of Dec inside the Q monad. The signature is this.

```
gen_allv_str_list :: [String] -> Q [Dec]
```

And when I get to execute it inside a splice a get an error as If I couldn´t execute Q[Dec] inside an splice.

This is the place where the splice gets executed

```
callGenerators :: Q Bool 
callGenerators = do 
                    $(gen_allv_str_list (notDefTypes uutTypesStr))
                    $(gen_arb_str_list (notDefTypes uutTypesStr))
                    return True
```

And the error I get:

```
    Couldn't match type `[Dec]' with `Exp'
    Expected type: ExpQ
      Actual type: Q [Dec]
    In the expression: gen_allv_str_list (notDefTypes uutTypesStr)
    In the splice: $(gen_allv_str_list (notDefTypes uutTypesStr))
```

I need the instances that are created by executing that code to be used in different functions. I would be very grateful if you can give me some clue with this problem.

Comment: `do` blocks expect expressions, but you've given it a list of declarations, which are only allowed at the top level.

Comment: I get the idea but what do you mean about top level? It has to be called from main function?

Comment: `callGenerators` is a top level declaration and definition. Other declarations you may recognize include `type Foo = Int` and `class Bar a where`. You can find the full grammar [here](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/syntax-iso.html#sect9.5).